# 3 congruent shapes in a $5 \times 5$ square board

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, coloring

Given a $5 \times 5$ board of $25$ cells. Is it possible to color $24$ of them in one of three colors in such a way, that the resulting three shapes of the particular colors are congruent to each other?

Comment: The wording is rather vague, I think. Could you be more precise?

Comment: There must be 8 cells of each color, so one cell will remain uncolored, no matter which one. Now each of the three colors gives one figure. The question is whether it is possible for them to be congruent, i.e. to have the same shape, at least after a reflection.

Comment: I tried out a parity argument based on a "chessboard" coloring of the cells, but it doesn't provide any new information.  Assuming that the corners of the "chessboard" are black, then all three subsets of the cells must either contain 4 black and 4 white cells (with one black cell left over), or two subsets have 5 black and 3 white cells while the other has 3 black and 5 white (with one white cell left over.)  Note also that all "grid congruences" either leave the number of black & white cells in a subset unchanged, or swap the black cells for white cells & vice versa.

Comment: @puzzler: Thank you. That is what I thought, but that made it much clearer! Perhaps you could edit your post accordingly?

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Fixed a non-critical bug pointed out by NickG in the comments, which prevented me from finding all possible solutions that didn't cover all but one cell.

---

This isn't, like, a super satisfying solution or anything...

But I ran a brute-force computer search, and failed to find any near-partition of the $5\times 5$ board into three congruent $8$-cell figures, connected or otherwise.

The search found five different *connected* $7$-cell figures whose congruent copies can be packed into a $5\times 5$ board (sometimes in more than one way). These are shown below:

[image: 7-cell packings]

---

My brute-force approach was to make a list of all transformations that can take some cells of the $5\times 5$ board to other cells. So my first list of candidates was all pairs of these transformations.

To each pair of transformations $(\tau_1, \tau_2)$, I associated a list of $25$ triples $(P, \tau_1(P), \tau_2(P))$ where $P$ ranges over all cells on the board. As a preliminary filter, I threw away all triples whose three elements were not pairwise distinct, or did not all fit on the board; then I threw away all pairs $(\tau_1, \tau_2)$ whose remaining triples did not cover at least $24$ cells of the board. *(Update: to find all $7$-cell figures, we need to reduce this number to $21$.)*

For each of the remaining $939$ pairs, I defined a graph on the triples, where two triples were adjacent if they shared one or more points, and then found a maximum independent set in the graph. Given any such independent set, we can get a packing of three congruent figures by taking the first element of every triple to be one figure, and applying $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ to get the other two figures.

None of these graphs had an independent set of size $8$, but some had an independent set of size $7$. (There were lots of solutions, so I filtered for connectedness and found only one remaining, up to symmetry.)

If anyone sees things I might've missed with the search, or can find a different connected $7$-cell figure that can be packed into a $5\times 5$ board (which would also show that my program can miss things), let me know.

---

**Update:** Generalizing to the next nontrivial case, my computer thinks that the $7\times 7$ board does not admit a packing of three congruent $16$-cell figures. There are multiple packings of three congruent $15$-cell figures, none of which are connected, though this one comes closest:

[image: 15-cell packing]

Comment: I haven't found any 8-cell solutions, but there are at least three other 7-cell solutions: [imgur image](http://imgur.com/a/Taw30)

Comment: @NickG Exccellent! That means my program has a bug in it, and all we need to do is find it.

Comment: Update: I found the bug. Unfortunately, it doesn't help us: the "bug" is that the symmetry groups for the other 7-cell solutions were not ones that could produce 8-cell solutions in principle: their set of triples did not cover 24 cells, only 21. So I'm not missing 8-cell solutions, but I'll redo the search later to find other 7-cell solutions.

Comment: The middle image in my solution has several minor variations, including changing the P-shapes to F-shapes. I've only done this by hand, so I'm interested in knowing if there are more.

Comment: @NickG Looks like I didn't find anything you didn't find. (I found $11$ solutions up to isometry and recoloring, with the $5$ congruent figures shown in the updated post; the second and third can be also altered by $180^\circ$ rotations and reflections of the purple shape, making $4$ variants each.)

Answer (score 2):

(1)[image]
(2)[image]

(3)[image]

One of them have two corners. Then in the case of $(1)$, another shape must be two corners, too.
However $(2,1)(4,1)(2,5)(4,5)$ can't devide to three areas.

In the case of $(2)$, we can't draw $(3,3), (5,1)$ or $(5,5)$ into a color, satisfying the condition.

In the case of $(3)$, if we draw the color of $(3,3)$, we can't make congruent shapes.
Therefore three congruent shapes are impossible.

Comment: What if the square the isn't colored is a corner?

Comment: @DanielV If it's colored, it isn't congruent.

Comment: @DanielV Either two corners are the same color anyway, or we have corners of three different colors, which falls under case (3).